# Firebird, how to convert (or downgrade) an fdb file version from 2.5 to 2.1...?

Tags: export, firebird2.5, firebird2.1

Please, is there a way to down-convert an fdb file that I am currently using on Firebird Server version 2.5 to a version 2.1.X file?

I have to deliver the fdb file to a user that only has Firebird Server 2.1.X installed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have not used any of the Firebird 2.5 features or syntax there are two options:

1. Backup the database using the gbak of Firebird 2.5 and restore it under Firebird 2.1 using the gbak of Firebird 2.1,
2. Recreate the database structure under 2.1 using your DDL scripts (or export the DDL using a tool like flamerobin or IB Expert), and then pump the data from the Firebird 2.5 database to Firebird 2.1 using a data pump tool.

You could also try to convince your client to upgrade to Firebird 2.5 (or Firebird 3), because Firebird 2.1 is no longer supported and not receiving updates.